# add-apt-repository is throwing strange errors (18.03)

Tags: command-line, add-apt-repository, wireshark

I was attempting to enable the wireshark repositories when following the guide that they give on their website, and when I ran

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:Wireshark-dev/stable
```

it returned these errors.

```bsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 136, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 868, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 398, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 355, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 338, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 295, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 95, in get_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_https(lp_url, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 90, in get_info_from_https
    return json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I'm still really new to using linux and am not familiar with terminal and some of its commands, some help would really be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: simple misspelling of the repository, stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: 18.03? You mean 18.04? BTW welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the repository that is causing the problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:wireshark-dev/stable # w in wireshark is case sensitive 
sudo apt update
```

Install wireshark from the default Ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo apt install wireshark
```

Comment: This won't solve the default python3 problem. Any other PPA won't add.

Comment: The name of the wireshark repository in the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:Wireshark-dev/stable` was misspelled. It could be a typo though.

Comment: I looked into the repos and on 18.04 `add-apt-repository` has `python3` shebang.

Comment: If you have any problems with Python 3.x please comment and I'll add my reply to your comment to my answer.